# Fetch products by categories id

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin

I need some help

My problem is how to display products by categories , note: i want to show the products in page index of my site ,and i have relationship bitween table products and categories.

Table products:
id, name, price, description, size, category_id

Table categories::
id, name

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to setup a one-to-many relationship between a category to many products. On the product model, add a category function like so:

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

and conversely, add this to your category model:

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function products()
{
    return $this->HasMany('App\Product');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The models need relations like @btl wrote, then if you want to display them on your blade you need to do something like this:

On Controller:

```
use App\Model\Category\Category;

    public function index(){
    $categories = Category::all();
        return view('app.index')->with('categories', $categories);
    };
```

Then on the view "app.index.blade.php":

```
<h1>Product By Categories</h1>
   @foreach($categories as $category)
    <div>
        <h2>Category: {{$category->name}}</h2>
        @foreach($category->products as $product)
            <div>
                <p>Product Name: {{$product->name}}</p>
                <p>Description: {{$product->description}}</p>
                <p>Size:{{$product->size}}</p>
                <p>Price: {{$product->price}}</p>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
   @endforeach
```

Comment: thank you my friend , but this code not work, it give me this error :Property [products] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: /var/www/html/smartshop/resources/views/smartshop/electro.blade.php)

Comment: it is looking for a property, seems like the "products" relations is not correctly defined, try to do on your controller dd(Category::find(1)->products); and see if it works